# Error converting datatype varchar to bigint- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a delete query in stored procedure but I keep getting the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

`request_id column` of workflow_status is of type `bigint` .

Below is what I am trying to do in my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @wp_ids_to_delete varchar(8000)
    
SET @wp_ids_to_delete = 'SELECT id FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())';

DELETE FROM [dbo].[workflow_status] 
WHERE request_id IN ( + @wp_ids_to_delete + );
```

The `SELECT` query works fine:

```
SET @SqlStatement_workflow_status = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[workflow_status] WHERE request_id IN (' + @wp_ids_to_delete + ')';
```

Comment: `@wp_ids_to_delete` contains the query string, it is not magically executed and replaced by the values you want to select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build a list and pass it to another statement (even if you were building the list correctly and `IN ('id1,id2')` was valid):

```
DELETE ws
  FROM dbo.workflow_status AS ws
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.wp_req AS wr
      WHERE wr.id = ws.request_id
      AND wr.creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example `SELECT` you believe to be working fine, is actually not a `SELECT` statement at all. It's a `SET` statement that is working fine because it is only setting a variable to a string value, that just so happens to be written in the form of a `SELECT` statement.

Similarly, your delete statement fails for the same reason. That is because you're asking it to delete rows where the `request_id` is in a string value, that the variable was set to. Below is what the overall effect of your statement, as you have it written, would be when it's executed. As you can see, the value of `'SELECT id FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())'` cannot be converted to an INT.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[workflow_status] 
WHERE request_id IN ( + 'SELECT id FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())' + );
```

Try this for you delete statement instead.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[workflow_status]
WHERE  request_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM [dbo].[wp_req]
    WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
)
```

Also, take into consideration how many rows will be deleted by this statement, and any triggers that may fire when you run it. It could cause a lot of blocking while it runs and overhead in your transaction log. For example, if you expect it to delete a few hundred thousand rows, or millions of rows, you may want to consider a batched approach where you delete around 10,000 rows at a time.

Comment: can't I have the result of this SQL string 'SELECT id FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())' stored into a variable and then use those ids in my IN clause ??

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` doesn't go "KABOOM"; that's not the same as it working the way you think it does.

If you were to do this:

```
SET @SqlStatement_workflow_status =  'Select * from [dbo].[workflow_status] where request_id IN (' +@wp_ids_to_delete + ')';
SELECT @SqlStatement;
```

You'd see that it returns:

```
Select * from [dbo].[workflow_status] where request_id IN (SELECT id FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Without it actually running that query.

Now the other two answers of putting the query represented by `@wp_ids_to_delete` in directly as a subquery will work, but I believe they can be improved upon, in terms of future maintainability, by using a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE s 
FROM [dbo].[workflow_status] s
INNER JOIN [dbo].[wp_req] r 
ON r.id = s.request_id
AND r.creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE());
```

Note, as Aaron points out in the comments, all 3 of the currently suggested answers work out into identical execution plans. There isn't a quicker or more efficient option of the 3; it's down to preferred style of query.

If you do want store the list of ID's as a comma seperated string for later use, then you could do:

```
SET @wp_ids_to_delete = SELECT STRING_AGG(id) FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE());
```

And your `SELECT` might become:

```
SET @SqlStatement_workflow_status =  'Select * from [dbo].[workflow_status] where request_id IN (' +@wp_ids_to_delete + ');';
EXEC @SqlStatement_workflow_status;
```

And your `DELETE` might become:

```
SET @delete_Statement = 'DELETE FROM [dbo].[workflow_status] 
WHERE request_id IN ( '+ @wp_ids_to_delete +' );';
EXEC @delete_Statement;
```

But, this may well be slower than other options.

Comment: FWIW all three will evaluate to the exact same execution plan.

Comment: FWIW? Not encountered that acronym before. Wasn't aware they'd evaluate to the same plan, although I figured any difference would likely be negligible - hence the "I believe" part, it's mostly a preference thing; I find `JOIN`s have a tendency to be easier to maintain over time than subqueries as the criteria evolves to become more complex.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=865367155f6d48e74add11634d1dbc4f - style is a funny thing, you think joins are better, I think exists is better because it matches what I'd want to do for a select when I don't need any data from the second table.

Comment: Fair play. Either way the OP now has 3 options that'll all work and they can choose whichever they prefer

Comment: can't I have the result of this SQL string 'SELECT id FROM [dbo].[wp_req] WHERE creation_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())' stored into a variable and then use those ids in my IN clause ??

Comment: @Gitesh I've just added an option for that; but I suspect it may well become more trouble than it's worth.